# What is cross compartment wrapper and how does it work?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm currently developing an addon for Firefox and I found out that lots of memories are used under cross compartment wrapper.

Could anyone tell me what cross compartment wrapper is and is there any ways to clear the memory under it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCWs are part of mozilla's [security model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Script_security). They exist for any references between different security compartments such as extension content scripts, different frames in a browser window or privileged contexts within the browser. Those wrapper objects are similar to javascript proxy objects.

A large number of CCWs may indicate that you're referencing a large amount of individual objects between the addon context and some other context, but without further details it's hard to tell.